# How do I know when an HTML element is available in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Excuse me if my question is not well asked, I will explain the problem.
I have an element `<div class="o_notification_manager"></div>` that appears after an uncertain time on the screen to display notifications. I want to make changes on this element as soon as it is displayed.

I thought of something like this with jquery

```
$(document.querySelector('.o_notification_manager')).ready(function() {
    console.log(document.querySelector('.o_notification_manager').innerHTML);
});
```

But I get this error
[image]

When I use the `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()` function, I get two error cases:

- Either my code runs before the element is displayed and I get the previous error;
- or my code runs after the element is displayed and the user sees the element change (he sees the content change, the width change).
  I want my code to run at the same time as the element is displayed.
  Any help is welcome.

Comment: Use a MutationObserver - see the duplicate for details and examples

Comment: Your best solution would be to hook into any events provided by the notification manager (if it's your manager, then add some), eg a "beforeShow" or "onshow" type event.   If not possible, then MutationObserver as noted above.

Comment: Regarding your error - you just need to add a check if it exists before making changes, if not loop again - but timeouts are more of a "hack" rather than a robust solution.

Comment: Thanks to you, your comments help me. I proceeded as follows:

var observer = new MutationObserver(_=> {
    if (document.contains($('div.o_notification_manager')[0])) {
        const bodyWidth = $('body').css('width');
        let targetNode = document.querySelector('div.o_notification_manager');
        targetNode.style.width = bodyWidth;
    }
});

observer.observe(mutationObject.target, {attributes: false, childList: true, characterData: true, subtree:true});`
`